# Why is my debian postinst script not being run?

Tags: package, debian, dpkg

I have made a `.deb` of my app using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki):

```
fpm -s dir -t deb -n myapp -v 9 -a all -x "*.git" -x "*.bak" -x "*.orig" \
--after-remove debian/postrm  --after-install debian/postinst \
--description "Automated build." -d mysql-client -d python-virtualenv home
```

Among other things, the `postinst` script is supposed to create a user for the app:

```
#!/bin/sh

    set -e

    APP_NAME=myapp

    case "$1" in
        configure)
            virtualenv /home/$APP_NAME/local
            #supervisorctl start $APP_NAME
        ;;

    # http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch9.en.html#s-bpp-lower-privs
       install|upgrade)

       # If the package has default file it could be sourced, so that
       # the local admin can overwrite the defaults

       [ -f "/etc/default/$APP_NAME" ] && . /etc/default/$APP_NAME

       # Sane defaults:

       [ -z "$SERVER_HOME" ] && SERVER_HOME=/home/$APP_NAME
       [ -z "$SERVER_USER" ] && SERVER_USER=$APP_NAME
       [ -z "$SERVER_NAME" ] && SERVER_NAME=""
       [ -z "$SERVER_GROUP" ] && SERVER_GROUP=$APP_NAME

       # Groups that the user will be added to, if undefined, then none.
       ADDGROUP=""

       # create user to avoid running server as root
       # 1. create group if not existing
       if ! getent group | grep -q "^$SERVER_GROUP:" ; then
          echo -n "Adding group $SERVER_GROUP.."
          addgroup --quiet --system $SERVER_GROUP 2>/dev/null ||true
          echo "..done"
       fi
       # 2. create homedir if not existing
       test -d $SERVER_HOME || mkdir $SERVER_HOME
       # 3. create user if not existing
       if ! getent passwd | grep -q "^$SERVER_USER:"; then
         echo -n "Adding system user $SERVER_USER.."
         adduser --quiet \
                 --system \
                 --ingroup $SERVER_GROUP \
                 --no-create-home \
                 --disabled-password \
                 $SERVER_USER 2>/dev/null || true
         echo "..done"
       fi

       # … and a bunch of other stuff.
```

It seems like the `postinst` script is being called with `configure`, but not with `install`, and I am trying to understand why. In `/var/log/dpkg.log`, I see the lines I would expect:

```
2012-06-30 13:28:36 configure myapp 9 9
2012-06-30 13:28:36 status unpacked myapp 9
2012-06-30 13:28:36 status half-configured myapp 9
2012-06-30 13:28:43 status installed myapp 9
```

I checked that `/etc/default/myapp` does not exist. The file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/myapp.postinst` exists, and if I run it manually with `install` as the first parameter, it works as expected.

Why is the `postinst` script not being run with `install`? What can I do to debug this further?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the example script you copied is simply wrong. `postinst` is not
supposed to be called with any `install` or `upgrade` argument, ever.
The authoritative definition of the dpkg format is the Debian Policy
Manual. The current version describes `postinst` in [chapter
6](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html)
and only lists `configure`, `abort-upgrade`, `abort-remove`,
`abort-remove`, and `abort-deconfigure` as possible first arguments.

I don't have complete confidence in my answer, because your bad example
is still up on debian.org and it's hard to believe such a bug could slip
through.

Comment: Ah, according to section 6.5 in Debian Policy Manual, it looks like it's _preinst_ that is run with `configure` and `install`. The Securing Debian Manual actually talks about "_preinst_ or _postinst_," so their example must be intended for _preinst_. I'll try to rearrange.

Comment: aha! that makes sense now. Do it in preinst if there's something else you're already doing in preinst that depends on the user being created. Otherwise postinst's $1 = configure branch. That's where most packages seem to do it according to my quick scan of /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.postinst

Comment: Maybe something has changed since 2012, but I think `postinst`s are run after installation, perhaps just in specific cases. I was installing phpMyAdmin on a Debian server and the installation, although prooving successful, was failing as a result of its `postinst` script. This led `apt-get` to think it wasn't properly installed. Once I tweaked `/var/lib/dpkg/info/phpmyadmin.postinst` it worked. Also, my system has 277 `postinst`s and only 75 `preinst`s, and running a script after installation seems more likely to me to be popular than after *removal*. Maybe it's just an ill-maintained package.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the answer provided by Alan Curry is incorrect, at least as of 2015 and beyond.
There must be some fault with the way the that your package is built or an error in the `postinst` file which is causing your problem.
You can debug your install by adding the `-D` (debug) option to your command line i.e.:

```
sudo dpkg -D2 -i yourpackage_name_1.0.0_all.deb
```

`-D2` should sort out this type of issue

for the record the debug levels are as follows:

```
          Number   Description
               1   Generally helpful progress information
               2   Invocation and status of maintainer scripts
              10   Output for each file processed
             100   Lots of output for each file processed
              20   Output for each configuration file
             200   Lots of output for each configuration file
              40   Dependencies and conflicts
             400   Lots of dependencies/conflicts output
           10000   Trigger activation and processing
           20000   Lots of output regarding triggers
           40000   Silly amounts of output regarding triggers
            1000   Lots of drivel about e.g. the dpkg/info dir
            2000   Insane amounts of drivel
```

The `install` command calls the `configure` option and in my experience the `postinst` script will always be run. One thing that may trip you up is that the `postrm` script of the "old" version, if upgrading a package, will be run **after** your current packages `preinst` script, this can cause havoc if you don't realise what is going on.
From the dpkg man page:
              Installation consists of the following steps:

```
          1. Extract the control files of the new package.

          2.  If  another version of the same package was installed before
          the new installation, execute prerm script of the old package.

          3. Run preinst script, if provided by the package.

          4. Unpack the new files, and at the same time back  up  the  old
          files, so that if something goes wrong, they can be restored.

          5.  If  another version of the same package was installed before
          the new installation, execute the postrm script of the old pack‐
          age.  Note that this script is executed after the preinst script
          of the new package, because new files are written  at  the  same
          time old files are removed.

          6.  Configure the package. 

          Configuring consists of the following steps:

          1.  Unpack  the  conffiles, and at the same time back up the old
          conffiles, so that they can be restored if something goes wrong.

          2. Run postinst script, if provided by the package.
```

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you are saying here about "the `install` command", but if it helps clarify things for anyone, `dpkg` will not ever call a postinst script with $1 = `install` or `upgrade`. Nothing stops you from supporting extra actions in your postinst if you want, but dpkg won't use them. The script posted in the original question doesn't work because it expects to be called with one of those. Perhaps this is the fault of fpm? I don't know.

Comment: @thepaul I thought that I was clear. `The install command calls the configure option `. Specifically, it will call the `postinst` script with `configure` and the `version` of the package e.g. `configure 6.4.0` (In my experience, of packaging my own software)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old issue that has been resolved, but it seems to me that the accepted solution is not totally correct and I believe that it is necessary to provide information for those who, like me, are having this same problem.

[Chapter 6.5](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-maintainerscripts.html) details all the parameters with which the preinst and postinst files are called

At https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts the installation and uninstallation flow is detailed.

Watch what happens in the following case:

apt-get install package
- It runs **preinst install** and then **postinst configure**

apt-get remove package
- Execute postrm remove and the package will be set to "**Config Files**"

For the package to actually be in the "**not installed**" state it must be used:

apt-get purge package

That's the only way we'll be able to run **preinst install** and **postinst configure** the next time the package is installed.